# Change color of different paraghraph in PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to make a function to color every paragraph in different color according to first letter of every paragraph in PHP. Like if my paragraph's first letter is Oil than this paragraph will be Orange.

I will have following kind of text.

```html
<div class="Message">
    <blockquote class="UserQuote">
        <div class="QuoteAuthor">
            <a href="/profile/tashrahs" rel="nofollow">Jimmy</a>said:
        </div>
        <div class="QuoteText">
            <p>
                <br>
                Ok I'll Let you Know.
            </p>
        </div>
    </blockquote>
    Thanks. Please Keep in Touch.
</div>
```

Comment: Anything you tried yet?

Comment: I don't even see what you "paragraphs" in this exmaple HTML code would be. Can you give an example with some more text and details?

Comment: Where is the PHP code that fills in the paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an associative array that maps each letter to a color:

```
$colors = array(
    'a' => 'aquamarine',
    'b' => 'blue',
    'c' => 'cyan',
    ...
)};
```

Then the code that creates a paragraph can do:

```
$color = isset($colors[$paragraph[0]]) ? $colors[$paragraph[0]] : 'black';
$html += "<p style='color: $color;'>$paragraph</p>";
```